# Export all cloud resources of a current project along with their locations

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are in the process of remodelling our cloud infrastructure. In an endeavor to do so, we need a list of all cloud resources in the project, along with below properties:

1. VPC/Subnet
2. Region
3. Zone

Is there a quick approach to do so?

Answer (score 3):

The GCP [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview) service seems like a good match for your needs.  This is an API/commands for working with the database of assets (things) in your GCP environment.  From this you can dump your resource definitions as well as request feeds for changes within the environment.

To get a current dump of resources, we can use `gcloud asset list` see [Listing assets](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/listing-assets).